# convert RGB buffer to HDC

Tags: winapi, rgb, borland-c++, gdi

I have utilized C++ Borland compiler to converted a JPG image to BMP RGB buffer and these are the output parameters I have at use

```
unsigned char* rgbpix;
unsigned int width;
unsigned int height;
```

I want to convert RGB buffer to HDC as I would like to make use of StretchBlt() windows API to downsize my image.

Pretty much I started with a JPG image and would like to have it converted to BMP and downsized. If you have any other ideas, please share.

Thank you for your input

Comment: You'll need to know the pixel format. Do you? That said, there are countless graphics libraries that can already do all this. Would be easier to use one.

Comment: Can you please give examples of a graphics library to make this conversion?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan pixel format is 24bpp

Comment: Well, websearch will do much better than I can

Comment: There's always GDI+, which has been a part of windows for overa decade now.You can load any image natively supported by windows and save to any one of nearly as many formats. You could also consider using StretchDIBits. You can give it a byte array and some info on the layout/format of the data and windows will magically do the scaling for you, right into a regular HDC. The GDI+ class you'd want to look at is `Image` or `Bitmap`. Here's a quick sample of loading a jpg. `HBITMAP result; Bitmap mImg(L"map.jpg", false);  mImg.GetHBITMAP(0, &result); return result;`